# Is there a free locally monoidal category?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, slice-category

One of the simpler free monoids is the list.

I think a list category would have lists of objects as objects and its maps would also be lists.

A list of maps `[a, b, c]` where `a: A -> A'`, `b: B -> B'`, `c: C -> C'` would map `[A, B, C] -> [A', B', C']`

Recursion is a bit messy but it's all simple enough.

What would a free "locally monoidal" category look like?

IIRC a locally Cartesian category basically possesses a symmetric monoid in `C/c` forall c.

A "locally monoidal" category would just have a monoid in C/c.

The details of a free locally monoidal category seem kind of messy to work out. It's not quite just a list of `C/c` because it needs to be a list forall c.

I suppose another possibly simpler approach would be a sort of difference list.

The category of endofunctors `C -> C` possesses a monoid.

I don't really get a category of "natural slice endofunctors" so to speak `forall x, C/x -> C/x` though

Comment: You seem to be using “possesses a monoid” to mean “has the structure of a monoidal category”, which is strange. Please clarify.

Comment: @ZhenLin yeah I just meant a monoidal category